# Mathjax Typeset method that takes markup rather than an element as parameter

Tags: javascript, mathjax

I have following JavaScript code, in which I am calling Typeset method of MathJax library and passing it a DOM element for typesetting. The callback method is typeSetDone in code below.

I would like to pass markup ( like $$x^2-2x+1=0$$) instead of a DOM element and get the resulting Mathjax html returned by the method call.

**Question** : Is this possible and if yes, then what method could I use?
I looked up the docs for Mathjax but could not find any such method.

```
MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset", MathJax.Hub, element, [typeSetDone, element]]);
```

Comment: There's no such method since MathJax v2 rendering depends on the DOM context. You could of course write a wrapper that temporarily creates a DOM node somewhere.

Comment: Ok.  That makes sense.

Comment: For what it's worth, MathJax v3 will have a method like this.